# Recent Votes is covered by Most votes

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

Today when I visit a Tools section Recent votes is covered by Most votes. First I think css is not load properly so I refresh page several time but still same result.
[image: Screen shot]

Its only happen on Reopen Votes section not in Close Votes section.

[image]

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No I don't see any console errors.